# Exportin/importing javascript modules

Tags: javascript

Nooby question:
I've got file main.js with module `let myModule = {}`, defined there inside `$(document).ready(function()`. And I have another file summary.js where I would like to use it. I declare them all in the head of html file:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/summary.js"></script>
```

I would like to use myModule module in the summary.js file and extend it. So I would like to be able to define: myModule.summary = {}. For now I receive the error `myModule is undefined` even though all js files are uploaded correctly (I can see them in debugger in dev console of the browser). I expect I have to export the mdrx module somehow but export default mdrx at the end of main.js does not do the job. How to do it correctly? I read the documentation but it seems like structural problem as I couldn't figure that out. Can that be that the myModule is not loaded yet before loding summary.js? If so how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type` attribute to achieve this:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then you can import the `module` in other `JavaScript` files:

```
import yourModule from './main.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the whole myModule was defined inside function() (called within document.ready event). Moving it outside that solved the problem.